# Misunderstanding about regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an example:

```
var p =  /^(\d)+$/;
var s = '834736';
var a = p.exec(s);
console.log(a);
```

I want to group the first digit `^(\d)`, but the result is:

```
["834736", "6"]
```

It catch the last digit. Anybody can explain to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to catch the first digit only, put the first digit in the group, and match the rest of the digits outside of the group, like so:

```
/^(\d)\d*$/
```

The reason you only catch the last digit is, that you repeat the same group for each digit you match. This means, every time it matches a new digit, the old contents of the group is replaced, and thus you get the last digit as the result of your group.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you show me why my above regex catch the last digit?

Comment: @BoodCarley You put the `+` outside the capturing group, so the capturing group only matched 1 digit at a time until it didn't match any more, at which point it contained the last digit.

Answer (score 2):

You should put the `+` inside the group or (if you only want the first digit) split the expression:

```
/^(\d)\d*$/
```